# Samba share not usable by PHP-FPM?

Tags: nginx, configuration, samba, php-fpm

I have a PHP-FPM and nginx setup that has been working perfectly on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04. The webserver's files are served from a directory called `/www`, which is set as the `root` of the server.

Initially, `/www` was mounted as a VMware shared folder (because the Ubuntu Desktop is running as a guest os). However, due to performance issues with shared folders (seeing a 2 second delay!), I am testing out samba shares.

I have a folder called `webfiles` shared as a network share on my Windows 7 host. I am able to automount it to `/www` by mounting it as cifs in my `fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.7/webfiles /www cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

The `/www` mounts fine on start up and I can create and delete files on it in Ubuntu. Nginx is also able to serve static files from it with no problem.

The problem is that once I want it to server PHP files through PHP-FPM, I start getting `File not found.` errors. This is despite the fact the setup worked perfectly, and the only thing that changed is, instead of a shared folder being mounted at `/www`, I now have a samba share.

I am not very familiar with samba, but what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a problem with the mounting. Instead of having windows pass the inode numbers, setting it so that Ubuntu generate the inode numbers fixes the problem:

```
//192.168.1.7/webfiles /www cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,noserverino 0 0
```